# How to automatically wrap lines with multicolumn and longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable

How can I automatically wrap lines in `longtable` with multi column? Below is my code, which doesn't wrap. Also, how can I decrease the font size?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}{
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{Self-learning capability in literature}  
\label{tab:self_learning_table} \\
\hline  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Literature}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Application}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Algorithm}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Literature}} & \multicolumn{1}{c} 
{\textbf{Application}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Algorithm}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\endfoot

\endlastfoot

1 &  \makecell{Process control} &  \makecell{Analytical solution, Fuzzy neural network12222222222222222222222222222222}\\ \hline


\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic LaTeX column types `c`, `l` and `r` do not wrap text inside them. In order to have wrapped text, you need to use the `p{...}` column specification, which takes an explicit column width.

Using the `array` package, it's simple to create a new column type that creates a wrapped centred column (although centering wrapped text is probably best avoided; if your text is long enough to wrap, it should probably be left aligned using just a `p` column.

Here's your document with a new column type `C` defined to require a maximum width, but with centred text inside. I've also shown the same table with a plain `p` column, which I think is the preferred format for this kind of text.

If you're not using a `longtable` environment, you can use the `tabularx` package to use `X` columns, which are self-adjusting `p` columns in a fixed total width table.

I've removed the `\makecell` macro from your sample document, which wasn't defined and doesn't seem relevant here.

As for changing the font size, if you're thinking about doing that for the text in the table to make it fit, this is almost always a bad idea. Instead you should find ways to make columns narrower or put the table in a landscape page if it is very wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{cC{1in}C{2in}}
\caption{Self-learning capability in literature}  
\label{tab:self_learning_table} \\
\hline  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Literature}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Application}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Algorithm}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Literature}} & \multicolumn{1}{c} 
{\textbf{Application}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Algorithm}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\endfoot

\endlastfoot

1 & Process control &  Analytical solution, Fuzzy neural network with some words that can be wrapped\\ \hline


\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{cC{1in}p{2in}}
\caption{Self-learning capability in literature}  
\label{tab:self_learning_table} \\
\hline  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Literature}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Application}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Algorithm}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Literature}} & \multicolumn{1}{c} 
{\textbf{Application}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Algorithm}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\endfoot

\endlastfoot

1 & Process control &  Analytical solution, Fuzzy neural network with some words that can be wrapped\\ \hline


\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `longtable` is better to use `xltabular`, which is combination of `longtable` and `tabularx` packages, where for the last column employ `X` column type.

Another possibilities is to use novel `tabularray` package. Using it the table code is much shorter and simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Self-learning capability in literature},
  label = {tab:self_learning_table} 
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec={ll X[l]},
                  row{1} ={font=\bfseries, c},
                  rowhead=1
                  }
Literature  
    &   Application         &   Algorithm           \\ 
1   & {Process\\ control}   &   \lipsum[1][1-2]     \\
2   & some text             &   \lipsum[1][3-5]     \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or width combination of `booktabs` package (call as `tabularray` library) and without vertical lines and only necessary horizontal rules as defined in the `booktabs` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Self-learning capability in literature},
  label = {tab:self_learning_table} 
                ]{colspec={@{} cl X[l] @{}},
                  row{1} ={font=\bfseries, c},
                  rowhead=1
                  }
    \toprule
Literature  
    &   Application         &   Algorithm           \\
    \midrule 
1   & {Process\\ control}   &   \lipsum[1][1-2]     \\
2   & some text             &   \lipsum[1][3-5]     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for correction of spelling error.

Comment: you're very welcome! I also happen to have typos that I don't always notice. and I'm glad someone corrects them. As I say, one should always re-read before posting…